# How do I add a Scrollbar to a tkinter Text Widget using .grid method

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a Scrollbar for my text widget however, I cannot seem to be able to grid() the scrollbar, thus the scrollbar does not appear on the text widget. Ignore what is in the variable Quote, it is just test data.

```
EventScrollBar= tk.Scrollbar(EventChoice)
EventText=tk.Text(EventChoice,height=25,width=50)
EventText.grid(row=3,column=1,columnspan=5)
EventScrollBar.config(command=EventText.yview)
EventText.config(yscrollcommand=EventScrollBar.set)
Quote=("""
...
wd""")
EventText.insert(tk.END,Quote)
EventText.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
```

Comment: Could you show a little more of your code please so we have a minimal, complete and verifiable example to test easily? Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note, variable names should be ```camelCase``` or ```under_scored```. I only say this as once you start using classes you may get naming conflictions which can be a real pain.

Answer (score 2):

I give you two ways of making a `Scrollbar`.

1) Using `tk.Scrollbar`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
EventText=tk.Text(root, height=10, width=50)
EventScrollBar= tk.Scrollbar(root, command=EventText.yview, orient="vertical")
EventScrollBar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
EventText.grid(row=0,column=0)
EventText.configure(yscrollcommand=EventScrollBar.set)
Quote=("""Suck\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\nee\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\nee\ned\ne\ne\nde\nd\ne\nded\nc\nc\nx\nc\nx\nc\nzc\ns\nds\nx\nwd\ns\nd\nwd""")
EventText.insert(tk.END,Quote)

root.mainloop()
```

2) Using `ScrolledText`

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tk.Tk()
Quote=("""Suck\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\nee\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\ne\nee\ned\ne\ne\nde\nd\ne\nded\nc\nc\nx\nc\nx\nc\nzc\ns\nds\nx\nwd\ns\nd\nwd""")
EventText = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root, height=10, width=50)
EventText.insert("end", Quote)
EventText.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: I feel kind of weird on seeing the quote. But that's what it was before Graham edited the OP's question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code shows no attempt to grid the scrollbar.

See below example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

ybar= tk.Scrollbar(root)
event_text=tk.Text(root, height=10, width=10)
ybar.config(command=event_text.yview)
event_text.config(yscrollcommand=ybar.set)

event_text.grid(row=0, column=0)
ybar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

for i in range(100):
    event_text.insert("end", "{}\n".format(i))

root.mainloop()
```

Just in case you are using `grid()` in your original code and forgot it here in your example your problem is likely due to the `columnspan=5`.

If you do that to your text widget then it will sit on top of your scrollbar.

Try something like this when using columnspan:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

ybar= tk.Scrollbar(root)
event_text=tk.Text(root, height=10, width=10)
ybar.config(command=event_text.yview)
event_text.config(yscrollcommand=ybar.set)

event_text.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)
ybar.grid(row=0, column=5, sticky="ns")

for i in range(100):
    event_text.insert("end", "{}\n".format(i))

root.mainloop()
```